# How to simulate from a log-copula function?

Tags: simulation, copula

Does anybody know how to simulate from a log-copula function?

I'm trying to simulate $(u,v)$ from a log-copula function with the CDF:
$$
C(u,v, a) = \exp\bigg(1-\big[(1 - \ln u)^a + (1 - \ln v)^a - 1\big]^{1/a}\bigg)
$$
I guess I should use [the Marshal-Olkin method](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.case.hu-berlin.de%2Fevents%2FArchive%2FWorkshops%2FCopulae%2Ftalks%2FHofert.pdf&ei=TXNgVdf2DoLeUfSWgJAC&usg=AFQjCNHv27gVmRlJI1hFYrfR_sOI9FZvZQ&sig2=DhoK6GUK2ccb2EH4dOgxaw&bvm=bv.93990622,d.d24), but don't know how.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the exact problem setup here?

Comment: Dougal, thanks for your reply. I'm trying to simulate (u,v) from a Log-copula function with the cdf, C(u,v, a) = exp{1-[(1 - ln u)^a + (1 - ln v)^a - 1]^{1/a}}. I guess I should use the Marshal-Olkin method, but don't know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1**

> Simulating from the copula  $$C_0(u,v, \theta) = (u^{-θ} + v^{-θ} −
>   1)^{-1/θ}$$ can be done by the following algorithm (see also [Embrechts et al., 2001](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/copchapter.pdf) for much more fascinating details):
>
> 1. Generate $U,V\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{U}(0,1)$
> 2. Take $W=(\{V^{-\theta/(1+\theta)}-1\}U^{-\theta}+1)^{-1/\theta}$
> 3. Return $(U,W)$

Now your copula is the transform
$$C_1(u,v,a)=\exp\{1-C_0(1-\log u,1-\log v,-a)\}\,.$$

---

For an Archimedian copula of the form $$C(u,v)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(u)+\varphi(v))$$it can be shown that the pair$$S=\varphi(U)/\{\varphi(U)+\varphi(V)\},\ T=C(U,V)$$is associated with the joint cdf$$G(s,t)=s\{t-\varphi(t)/\varphi^\prime(t)\}=sK(t)$$(see [Wu et al., 2006](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~veronica/ME601701/paper4.pdf)) which means $S$ and $T$ are independent and can be simulated as

1. Generate $R,S\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{U}(0,1)$
2. Take $T=K^{-1}(R)$
3. Take $U=\varphi^{-1}(S\varphi(T))$ and $V=\varphi^{-1}((1-S)\varphi(T))$